# pipe operator not supported with : Angular[Typescript] - rxjs - combineLatest

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, rxjs, combinelatest

### The Code with the proplem

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AccountingTransactionsStoreService } from './accounting-transactions-store.service';
import { GeneralLedgerAccountsStoreService } from './general-ledger-accounts-store.service';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountingReportsStoreService {


  constructor(
    private accountingTransactionsStore: AccountingTransactionsStoreService,
    private   generalLedgerAccountsStore: GeneralLedgerAccountsStoreService) 
    {}

  readonly generalLedgerAccountsTransaction$
    = combineLatest(
      this.accountingTransactionsStore.selectedPeriodAccountingTransactionsFlate$,
      this.generalLedgerAccountsStore.selectedOrganizationGeneralLedgerAccountsTree$)
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
      .pipe(
        map(([transactionsFlat, accountsTree]) => {
          if (transactionsFlat && accountsTree)
            return [];
          else return [];
        })
      )
}
```

### The Error

> Property 'pipe' does not exist on type ' OperatorFunction < unknown , [ unknown , AccountingTransactionFlatInterface [ ] , GeneralLedgerAccountInterface [ ] ] > ' .

Comment: pipe must concatenated like `pipe(distinctUntilChanged(),map([transactionsFlat, accountsTree]) => {...}))` -only one pipe separated by commas the operators-

Comment: @Eliseo thanks❤,  I'm no near a computer, can you provide me with good link to read more later on the this oprater , i need the best one for step by step understanding , I will read it later ,and add a summary to the anser ❤

Comment: only know the official https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/91088dae1df097be2370c73300ffa11b27fd0100/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @Eliseo thanks again ❤  readding the original docs is allways the best way to get the core team intend 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Whats Wrong?

```js
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

### Why ?

For real Not sure , but i looks like it's about fiunction defntion Overloads

#### Update from ❤ [Ingo Burk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796139/pipe-operator-not-supported-with-angulartypescript-rxjs-combinelatest/58796140#comment103873830_58796140)

> combineLatest exists both as an operator and a function cresting an observable from multiple others. The operator version is deprecated, however. Depending on the import you get one or the other.

## How to solve it

import ***combineLatest*** from ***'rxjs'*** not from ***'rxjs/operators'***

```js
import { distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { combineLatest} from 'rxjs';
```

### How did I found the solution?

- removed the rxjs imports
- used vscode ***add all missing imports*** by accident (I prefare by  trial and error )
- [image]

### What I learned ? is there pattern ?

- yes and no , it's not a pattern , but a trick!‍♀️
- try to remove imports
- and use ***add all missing imports***
- then let ***VSCode*** decide what to import
- then observe the difference
- then use my jujment.
- because ***VSCode*** has more knowledge of my code in it's memeory than me ‍♀️

Comment: combineLatest exists both as an operator and a function cresting an observable from multiple others. The operator version is deprecated, however. Depending on the import you get one or the other.

Comment: @IngoBürk thanks  i'm new to the rxjs , using for 1st in this project  , th

Comment: TIP: Use the documentation here: https://rxjs.dev/api If it says it is under the `operators` heading, it is imported from `rxjs/operators`. Everything else is in `rxjs`.